# android: How to change layout on buttonclick using ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am working on an android application. I am using ViewPager to provide som presentation of the app. I would like to change layout from pager to another on button click. I know how to change layout on button click without using viewpager. Can anybody help me?

Here is my piece of code

This is the onCreate method in main activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });

    }
```

This is the activity I want to go to after clicking the button:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.sowo.sk");
    }
```

Then there is the layout, where is only viewpager a this is how the single fragment looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/sli1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ďakujeme, že využívate naše služby."
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#170c0c"
        android:background="#daa520"
        android:text="Prihlásiť"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#daa520"
        android:textColor="#170c0c"
        android:text="Registrovať"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="VITAJTE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:src="@drawable/set"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>


       </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the layout I want to move to after clicking the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

EDIT:
An I forgot to provide piece of fragment class code:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout,container,false);
    }

}
```

EDIT2:

I tried to change fragment like this, but it did not help:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Button next = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false).findViewById(R.id.button);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout,container,false);
    }


}
```

Of course this does not work. Because first I am loading viewpager layout a it changes to fragment layouts and I want to click the button, that was not loaded yet. Or I only think, that this is the problem. But how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you able to see the button when the first activity loads?

Comment: first activity layout looks like this: ´<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>´ and it turns to fragment_one_layout, that is written above in the post and there ist the button visible.

Comment: then you should set the  onClick listener of the button in onViewCreated method of the first fragment.

Comment: OK, And how will I get the ID of the button in this class? findViewById does not work.

Comment: I tried something. But it did not work. See EDIT2.

Comment: Please see my answer to get how findViewById works in fragment. And sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this way to get the id of the button.

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout,container,null)
        Button next = (Button)content.findViewById(R.id.button);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

        return content;
    }


}
```

Comment: inflate did not take the null atribute, but with false it worked. Many thanks.